# Pandas - memory error while importing a CSV file of size 4GB

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I tried importing a csv file of size 4GB using `pd.read_csv` but received **out of memory** error. Then tried with `dask.dataframe`, but couldn't convert to `pandas dataframe` ( same memory error).

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv(#file)
df = df.compute()
```

Then tried to use the `chunksize` parameter, but same memory error:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(#file, chunksize=1000000, low_memory=False)
df = pd.concat(df)
```

Also tried using `chunksize` with lists, same error:

```
import pandas as pd
list = []
for chunk in pd.read_csv(#file, chunksize=1000000, low_memory=False)
    list.append(chunk)
df = pd.concat(list)
```

**Attempts:**

1. Tried with file size 1.5GB - successfully imported
2. Tried with file size 4GB - failed (memory error)
3. Tried with low `chunksize` (2000 or 50000) - failed (memory error for 4GB file)

> Please let me know how to proceed further?
>
> I use python 3.7 and RAM 8GB.
>
> I also tried the Attempt 3 in a server with RAM 128GB, but still `memory error`
>
> I cannot assign `dtype` as the csv file to be imported can contain different columns at different time

Comment: reading a chunk and then storing it in a list `list.append(chunk)` doesn't make any sense (because the list is taking your memory). You need to process the chunk as you load it (agregate it, filter it, or whatever) before loading the next one. The 128gb server should, imho, work. My guess is that something is limiting the memory of your process (docker?)

Comment: I don't want to (agregate it, filter it, or whatever) the chunk, I just want to append all the chunks and build a complete `dataframe` out of it. Post which I will use this entire `dataframe` for filtering and aggregation using `GUI toolkit`

Comment: well you do not have enough memory to do it. Imagine you have a bookshelf with capacity for 100 books (your ram) and you want to fit in 200 books. If you `read_csv()` without chunksize. You take all 200 books at once and place them there - they don't fit. If you set `chunksize` you take 10 books at once, put them there. After 10 rounds you do not have any room in bookshelf left so you run out of memory.

Comment: To put things simply, I want to build a dataframe out a heavy CSV file without involving any processing. I would like to skip the processing phase because the csv file will not contain the same number of columns at every instance.

Comment: @user1404 yes, and as others have stated, you don't have enough memory to materialize the entire dataframe.

Comment: @user1404 What do you want to do with the dataframe in the end? Load it and then exit?

Comment: "I also tried the Attempt 3 in a server with RAM 128GB, but still memory error" I find that surprising. Are you using a 32bit version of Python, by chance?

Comment: Thank you very much Robin Nemeth! I clearly understood. I should stop wasting my time in this.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes I'm using 32Bit version of Python 3.7

Comment: Then that's your problem, you won't be able to access more than a 32bit address space, so around 4gb *maximum* although many operating systems limit it to less. For example, the limit is 2 gb on windows.

Comment: @RobinNemeth Once I generate the full dataframe, I intend to display it using a GUI toolkit where the end user can perform operations ( like sum, mean, filter, change values, change dtype).

Answer (score 0):

Already been answered here:
[How to read a 6 GB csv file with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas)

I also tried the above method with a 2GB file and it works.

Also try to keep the chunk size even smaller.

Can you share the configuration of your system as well, that would be quite useful

Comment: Welcome to SO, Nischal! I would advise you to read the comments under the OP. We have figured out that lowering the chunk size wouldn't acomplish anything and the issue with 128GB ram server is due to OP using 32bit Python.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to record what I tried after getting enough suggestion! Thanks to Robin Nemeth and juanpa

1. As juanpa pointed I was able to read the csv file (4GB) in the
   server with **128GB RAM** when I used `64bit python` executable file
2. As Robin pointed out even with a 64bit executable I'm not able to
   read the csv file (4GB) in my local machine with **8GB RAM**.

So, no matter what we try the machine's RAM matters as dataframe uses **in memory**